# one directory for c file which must compile first without main in funcs/ directory& c file wth main function &common header file in separate directory

Tags: c, header-files, makefile

I have two source files and common header file. header file is like following

```
#ifndef TEST
#define TEST

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <time.h>


#define PORT 5000
#define BUF_SIZE 20000
#define MAIN "GET / HTTP/1.1" //initial
#define REQUEST "GET /add?"//with query
#define SOCKET_BUFFER 2048
#define SEEK_SET 0
#define SEEK_CUR 1
#define SEEK_END 2
#define MAIN_RETURN 2
#define CSS_RETURN 3
#define REQUEST_RETURN 4

int SET_MAIN=0;

int ads_today=0;
int process(int size,char buffer[size],char status);
int min(int a, int b);
ssize_t sendfile(int out_fd, int in_fd, off_t *offset, size_t count);

#endif
```

I am getting error that sounds like I am including my common header file twice. common header file exists in `./headers/` directory. main function source file which contains main function is in `./` directory which is root of small project

My make file is like following

```
FUNCS = funcs/
HEADERS = headers/
HEADER_FROM_FUNCS_DIR=../$(HEADERS)

lh : $(FUNCS)test_func.o test.o
    cc -o lh $(FUNCS)test_func.o test.o 

test_func : $(FUNCS)test_func.c $(HEADERS_FROM_FUNCS_DIR)/test.h
    cc -c $(FUNCS)test_func.c

test.o : test.c $(HEADERS)/test.h
    cc -c test.c

clean :
    rm lh $(FUNCS)test_func.o test.o
```

since I have defined `#ifndef` directive in `.h` file so I really don't know why my both source files including .h in `lh` executable which is my final program supposed to be in root of project directory result of `user #: make` command

project directory structure

```
./test.c #with main function
./headers/test.h # 
./funcs/test_func.c #without main function, must be compiled first which is supporting file with functions
```

Can I fix this error, thanks

Also `How not to hard code file names in Makefile`. I really don't mind keeping names for output files but I really hate source file names in Makefile that I must hard code names of source files and header files in Makefile, Is there a way to get rid of hardcoded file names like use some sort of built-in Make flags that will help compile source files with any names and include header files

make outputs

version_1# make

```
cc    -c -o funcs/test_func.o funcs/test_func.c
cc -c test.c
cc -o lh funcs/test_func.o test.o 
/usr/bin/ld: test.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `SET_MAIN'; funcs/test_func.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: test.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `ads_today'; funcs/test_func.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:6: lh] Error 1
```

Comment: Why do you think, that specific file must be compiled first? In C the order of compilation typically doesn't matter. You just need to have all bits&pieces together when you call the linker.

Comment: You are definining those variables inside the header and as a result they will be defined in each C file including that header. That is nothing related to your include guards or to compilation order. You should only put declarations into headers and put definitions into C files that you link.

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks it worked. if I need to declare variable named `x` with int type how should I write it to declare it, please tell

Comment: You put `extern int x;` in the header and `int x = <value>;` into the C file that shall define it.

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks for repeating. I have just corrected it. Can u also please add how can I remove file names of source files and header files in Makefile, I really don't like to hard code files names in `Makefile`

Comment: That would be topic for a different question. And I am not really into makefiles. Someone else might answer that other question.